# Why isn't there any entry in Sql Server Profiler between "Begin Transaction" and "Rollback Transaction"?

Tags: sql-server, transactions, sql-server-profiler

I'm trying to troubleshoot the following scenario:

A transaction is opened, a record is deleted, and then after many (obtuse) lines of code, that record is attempted to be re-inserted.  At this point, a duplicate key exception is thrown.

My gut tells me that the insert is happening in a different transaction than the deletion, but I am not sure how to verify this.

I am running Sql Server Profiler and have checked off the columns for TransactionID and EventSubClass, and have selected the EventClass of "SQLTransaction".

I see many different transactionIDs.  I also see (for several of the same transactionIDs BEGIN and ROLLBACK with no events in between.  Why would that be?  Wouldn't I see some SQL that was executed after the BEGIN?  I am seeing this in several places.

So, to recap:
(1) Why wouldn't I see any SQL in between a BEGIN and ROLLBACK transaction?
(2) Any thoughts on what might be happening with the insert?

Comment: In your Profiler trace, are you selecting any of these events:  `Stored Procedures Group`:  RPC:Completed, SP:Completed, SP:StmtCompleted  --OR--
`TSQL Group`:  SQL:BatchCompleted, SQL:StmtCompleted

Comment: Yup, the following: Stored Procedures Group: RCP:Completed and under TSQL Group: SQL:BatchCompleted, SQL:StmtCompleted.  I will add the SP:Completed, SP:StmtCompleted though.  Thanks.

Comment: Okay, added the other 2 - still nothing.  Any ideas?

Comment: You should post the trace output. If available, I bet someone can help.  Lotsa' smart SQL pros here on SO...

Comment: There's a BEGIN TRAN, a DELETE, and an INSERT, right?  Are they all from the same SPID?

Comment: there was only a BEGIN TRANS and a ROLLBACK  - no delete or insert in between those 2 entries. I did see a delete and an insert separately, but I would like to understand why I would see something like this in Profiler.  FWIW, I did figure out my specific problem, but I am still curious if there's something I'm missing that I could leverage next time :-)